# Avoiding Sonarlint error efficiently in Java for infinite while loop

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, sonarqube, sonarlint, sonarlint-eclipse

I have a RabbitMQ Consumer Java application that keeps on checking for the new message on the queue with a while(true) loop.

Is there any solution so I can avoid following Sonalint **Blocker bug** without suppressing the error:

> Loops should not be infinite

Reference : https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/RSPEC-2189

Comment: Please show a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and link to the [rule](https://rules.sonarsource.com/) you are talking.

Comment: Reference: https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/RSPEC-2189

Comment: According to the RabbitMQ documentation no `while (true) { ... }` loop is needed for that: https://www.rabbitmq.com/api-guide.html#consuming